# Add tasks to team members outlook calenders via spreadsheet in Sharepoint

Tags: outlook, office-integration

Sharepoint newbie - we have a excel spreadsheet in sharepoint that contains task due dates for people in our team.  Is there a way to automate adding the tasks and their due dates to peoples outlook calendar?

thanx

John A.

Answer (score 1):

If you use a task list instead of excel, then everyone on your team can connect the task list to outlook and then when tasks are added, they will automatically show up in outlook.

If you want it on their outlook calendar instead of the outlook task list, do the same thing but use an Events list.  Then customize the columns you need for it.

Comment: The caveat being that they show up in Outlook as separate lists that can be viewed.  They don't merge into your personal calendar or tasks without manually copying them over.